# Better way to read a csv file

Tags: python, file, csv

I need to read specific columns from a csv file and manipulate the code based on data inside the columns. I am not happy with the way I've hard-coded the columns. I'm sure Python provides with a better way of doing what I have done. Does anyone have a better suggestion of doing the below stuff especially reading the specific 10 columns from csv:

```
import csv
import os
import sys

file_csv = sys.argv[1]

Cat1=[]
Cat2=[]
Cat3=[]
Cat4=[]

with open(file_csv,'rb') as f:
    next(f)
reader=csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
for col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10 in reader:
    Cat1.append(col2)
    Cat2.append(col4)
    Cat3.append(col8)
    Cat4.append(col10)

datadict = zip(Cat1, Cat2, Cat3, Cat4)

for files, path, fname, pid in datadict:
    bla bla bla
```

Comment: Not sure what `datadict` is doing there because the names used in the zip are not assigned anywhere; I answered it based on the CSV reading bit.

Comment: Hi, sorry! I copied the wrong code in there. My bad! Have edited the code now..

Answer (score 1):

A [`DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) will convert your rows into dictionaries with the key being the column name, resulting in this:

```
with open(file_csv,'rb') as f:
   reader = csv.DictReader(f)
   lines = list(reader)

for line in lines:
   print line['column1']
   print line['column2']
   # ...
```